# Unicode(\u2079) rendering issue in D3 graph in iOS 8.3 hybrid application

Tags: javascript, ios, d3.js, unicode, ios8.3

I needed to show y-axis label as '10 power 9 per Litre' in the application I am working on.[image]I have Just provided the following text to D3 graph: '10\u2079/L'.Everything works well till iOS 8.2. From iOS 8.3 onwards it shows some other character instead of superscript 9. Same text with unicode character renders correct in other parts of application except in D3 graphs. Inspecting the element in graph shows correct character but not in the application WebView.
Plz refer the images attached for understanding and help me understand the reason. Thanks in advance.

[image: actual unicode text]
[image: unicode text inside graph]
[image: Element inspection inside graph]

Comment: have you tried specifying the font-family for the text? from the screenshot with the crossed rectangle looks like the font is different (look at the 1 which is different) and missing that glyph. so declare a font-family that has that glyph and that should probably fix the issue

Comment: Thanks. it solved my problem. I wonder How it worked for earlier versions.Probably iOS 8.3 has removed the font I have been using.

Comment: the different versions of iOS probably have different fonts set as standard, and so they have different glyphs I guess. I'll post that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the font-family for the text, from the screenshot with the crossed rectangle looks like the font is different (look at the 1 which is different) and missing that glyph.

so declaring a font-family that has that glyph should fix the issue